# I can't insert data into my database. Always uses the else part of the code

Tags: php, sql

The goal is to place values in a database. I can't find my error. It always takes me through the else in my code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contact`(`id`, `date`, `name`, `email`, `message`)
 VALUES ([0],[$datum],[$name],[$email],[$message])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{?> <html><br><br><a href="home.php">Back to homepage.</a></html><?php;}
else
{?><html><br><br><p>Message failed</p></html><?php;}
```

I always get the page with message failed instead of back to homepage.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: what does insert into concat mean??

Comment: Also there is a difference between **'** and **`**

Comment: insert into contact is chosing wich database the variables should be insterted to. I will check the difference! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change query like this, [ ] are used for array

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `contact`(`id`, `date`, `name`, `email`, `message`)
 VALUES (NULL,'$datum','$name','$email','$message')";
```

Keep blank to id part , it should be auto increment.

Comment: If `id` is auto-increment, then you should be sending `NULL`.